# InvalidSignatureException while trying to Invoke Lamba using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-glue

I am invoking aws lambda function with 'RequestResponse' Invocation type and getting this error:

I have already searched to see its solution supported in other aws SDK's, but can not find any solution for python boto3.

Edit: I am using AWS Glue python shell job to run my code, so I can not control system time.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/tmp/glue-python-libs-dgQjkA/audit_api_handler.py", line 532, in get_jobs_by_job_types
return self.get_api_response(method, params)
File "/tmp/glue-python-libs-dgQjkA/audit_api_handler.py", line 591, in get_api_response
LogType='Tail', Payload=json.dumps(post_data).encode())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions
.
ClientError
:
An error occurred (InvalidSignatureException) when calling the Invoke operation: Signature expired: 20190712T122841Z is now earlier than 20190712T122841Z (20190712T123341Z - 5 min.)
```

Comment: Did you check whether your local system time is correct?

Comment: @MartinLöper I'm using AWS Glue python shell, so I can't control system time apparently I guess.

Comment: Do you have stateless restrictions on the outgoing (or incoming) traffic for the subnet (such as NACL) in which your glue job is launched?

Comment: @MartinLöper Well my glue job uses a glue connection that limits it to a VPC. That VPC does not have any NAT due to security concerns.
Removing that connection apparently solved my problem.

I was just thinking if it is caused because glue job can't sync its time to the real world.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what a glue connection is? :)
I asked the question about the network traffic filter because I remembered a similar case for one of our VPN servers which could not sync time because I blocked the Network Time Protocol (NTP) port UDP 123 via NACL. ;)

Comment: So I understand correctly that your boto3 issue came from a network configuration that was too restrictive or did not have outgoing internet access? That would be important to formulate a good answer to let other SO users know if they face the same issue.

Comment: @MartinLöper Glue connection is used to access the databases that reside in a VPC and don't any any public IP address. Glue connection is a configuration that let's Glue job connect to such databases.
Yet, it restricts glue job to the VPC network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I appreciate @Martin Loper's answer as it explains the cause of the problem, I couldn't remove connection from the glue job, as it was required to communicate with the database, and I also couldn't add NAT in the VPC as it was a security requirement.
My problem was solved when I used this at the start of the job:

```
boto3.setup_default_session(region_name="us-east-1")
```

It makes sure that each boto3 client uses us-east-1 as its region.

Update:
Although it's much less frequent, but this issue still persists.

Comment: Cool that you found a better workaround for this issue! Do you know why it works this way?

Comment: My take is that Glue Jobs don't initially know their region internally. While, not having internet access they can't sync their time either and so sometimes when time mismatch occurs aws servers fail to tell if it's a valid boto3 client call.
Adding region manually may or may not sync time but will make sure that aws servers identify its caller and the region of the resources it has to consume.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Glue provisions a Spark environment running on a virtual instance for every Glue job you create.
The time syncing issue most probably is caused by the glue job's underlying instance not being able to request the current time via NTP.

As clarified in the comments, the glue job had a connection configured to access data stores. For this configuration, the AWS docs [1] state that:

> If a job needs to run in your VPC subnet—for example, transforming data from a JDBC data store in a private subnet—AWS Glue sets up elastic network interfaces that enable your jobs to connect securely to other resources within your VPC.
>   [...]
>   No public IP addresses are assigned. [...]
>
> If your job needs to access both VPC resources and the public internet, the VPC needs to have a Network Address Translation (NAT) gateway inside the VPC.

As confirmed in the comments, a **missing NAT gateway for the VPC which is assigned to the glue connection** (for data store access) caused the boto3 time syncing issue.
AWS Glue creates a separate ENI for the glue connection inside the given subnet of the VPC and routes all traffic of the underlying instance through this ENI. If the ENI cannot route traffic to the outside world, time apparently cannot be synced.

**Note:** What confused me here is, that AWS EC2 on the other hand does not need public internet access for time syncing (as described in the docs [2]). So either they are not using EC2 to host the underlying instance or it is not configured in accordance to the docs. Maybe an AWS guy on this forum could tell us more??

#### References

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/start-connecting.html
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html